# How to handle "no internet connection" scenario when sending requests?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm currently developing an instant message application based on FCM (Firebase Cloud Message). My problem lies in the follow scenario:

1. User is connected to an intermitent network - i.e. a wi-fi that, although holds the connection with the device, might lose internet connection from time to time with the internet provider;
2. User attempts to send a message (a POST request using volley) when the device is connected to the wi-fi but with no internet connection;

What is the best way to tackle this issue? So far, I've implemented a listener for network change using BroadcastReceiver, however, it is not enough to deal with the scenario described above once the wi-fi connection is not lost.

Comment: I dont use volley, but I'm sure you can receive a timeout event for the request. I would implement some mechanism to retry it automatically. You could also warn the user and ask him to retry manually. Based on whatsapp I think what they do is just to retry later automatically, silently, if something fails.

Comment: Is there any good practice about how many retries should I try? Should I wait before attempting to send it again?

Answer (score 3):

I created my own utility class for that. Whenever I want to make a network call I use the callbacks whenever its a success or a failure. The Library in use is [MaterialDialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static boolean isOnline() {
    InetAddress inetAddress = null;
    try {
        Future<InetAddress> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Callable<InetAddress>() {
            @Override
            public InetAddress call() {
                try {
                    return InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
        inetAddress = future.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        future.cancel(true);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inetAddress != null && !inetAddress.equals("");
}


public static MaterialDialog checkConnectivity(final Activity activity, final NetworkUtilCallback callback) {
    MaterialDialog dialog = MaterialDialogUtil.builDialogPositiveNegative(activity,
            activity.getString(R.string.no_internet),
            activity.getString(R.string.instruction_no_internet),
            "RETRY",
            "CANCEL",
            new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(MaterialDialog dialog, DialogAction which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (!isOnline()) {
                        checkConnectivity(activity, callback);
                    } else {
                        callback.onSuccess();
                    }
                }
            },
            new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(MaterialDialog dialog, DialogAction which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    callback.onCancel();
                }
            });
    if (!isOnline()) {
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        callback.onSuccess();
    }

    return dialog;
}

public interface NetworkUtilCallback {
    void onSuccess();

    void onCancel();
}
```

Comment: Nice! So you ask the user if he want to try again. As my application is an IM, I think I'll retry it automatically. My concern now is how many times and from how long will I wait untill I try again

Comment: @EdgarDaSilvaFernandes That's up to you. You can modify the code for your needs :)

Answer (score 2):

**In your manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**And the condition to check before performing server requests!**

```
public static boolean hasInternetConnection()
{
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected())
{
    return true;
}
NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected())
{
    return true;
}
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected())
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: This has the problem that it does not give any information about having a valid internet connection. Because it will be true for having a connection to  WiFi, but the WiFi may not have internet access.